Retrieve rows for earlier transactions where key is in row being retrieved
I have a table of data being read into Power Query that for example contains the following data:



Job ID
Year
Month
Value
Type




1234
2023
11
123.45
A


1234
2024
01
65.00
C


1234
2024
02
375.48
B


1234
2024
03
500.56
A


1234
2024
04
245.12
A



I am searching for entries where the Year = 2024 and Month = 03, and then I need to retrieve all the earlier rows that contain any Job ID that exists in my current search data but only upto where the Type for the row is not C and no earlier entries for that particular Job ID once this Type has been found.
So for the data above I want to be retrieving the following data.



Job ID
Year
Month
Value
Type




1234
2024
02
375.48
B


1234
2024
03
500.56
A



There could be several JOB ID's in a month so I cannot filter on this in the first table.
I have created a single table filtering by YEAR and MONTH to get the jobs for current month that I am interested in. Using this table I have joined using LEFT OUTER to the original data table which has been filtered by (YEAR = 2024 and Month <= 03) or (YEAR < 2024) this retrieves all data rows. I now need to learn how can I only retrieve those rows upto and after where the TYPE = C?

Here is a workaround for you. You can create two tables for filtering.
year = DISTINCT('Table'[Year])
month = DISTINCT('Table'[Month])

Do not create relationships between tables.
then create a measure
MEASURE =
IF (
    MAX ( 'Table'[Year] ) = MAX ( 'year'[Year] )
        && MAX ( 'Table'[Month] ) < MAX ( 'month'[Month] )
        && MAX ( 'Table'[Type] ) <> "C",
    1
)

add this measure to visual filter and set to 1.

